# How can I configure Visual Studio to cleanly separate source files, project settings, and temporary files?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Visual Studio makes quite a mess in how your source files, project settings, build files, and other temporary files are (mostly) dumped into the same directory.

Ideally these should be cleanly separated to help with browsing the project, and deciding what gets committed to the repo and what is ignored.

How can I configure Visual Studio to clean this mess up?

MODERATORS: I refuse to reword this post and my question. The post and its question was perfectly clear and was given a perfectly clear answer; it was not in the slightest opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source files**

You pretty much constrained to the folder your project resides in. In there you can create folders as you please and put source files wherever you like.

`<root>/<Project Name>/`

**Project files**

You can't change the location of that file. The project settings are always in `<root>/<Project Name>/<ProjectName>.*proj`

**Build files**

These can be changed in Visual Studio. Goto `Project Properties -> Compile`. There you can change the output directory for each compilation setting.

**Intermediate files (obj folder)**

This folder can only be changed in your project settings file. Find the appropriate configuration and add a `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` key with the destination folder inside.

Example: `<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>C:\foo</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>`

---

There is a lot more to configure directly with the Project settings file. A full description of all keys can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)

---

If you enable source control with Visual Studio, it already creates a pretty lengthy `.gitignore` which already ignores the `/bin` and `/obj` folder so if you don't mind having these folders in your project folder, you don't really need to configure anything.